# 1080p resolution is not coming for iOS devices using getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, getusermedia

I am recording video by using getUserMedia API. I am passing below constraints to getUserMedia API in-order to record video.

```
constraints  = {
     video: {
         width: { min: 1920, ideal: 1920 },
         height: { min: 1080, ideal: 1080},
         facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
     },
     audio: false
}
```

This constraints are working fine for Android but for iOS it is giving an error "OverConstrainedError".
Later i have changed the constraints so that it is working fine in iOS too. Please find the updated constraints below.

```
constraints  = {
      video: {
          width: 1920,
          height: 1080,
          facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
      },
      audio: false
}
```

But here the issue is the video stream which is coming from getUserMedia is of 720p resolution. I need Full HD i.e 1080p resolution. I am getting Full HD resolution for Android devices but for iOS devices i am getting HD resolution only.
If anyone faced the same issue then please tell me how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What iOS devices are you using?

Comment: iPhone x, iPad 2017

Comment: If you want try checking these exception https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Exceptions but I think that the problem is that `getUserMedia` isn't supported well yet in ios devices as you can see here https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/ it's still an `Experimental Feature`